# Patching multiple resources with Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a kustomization.yaml file defined which consists of two resources that are downloaded from a git repo. Both of these resources want to create a `Namespace` with the same name, which creates an error when I try to build the final kustomization file: `may not add resource with an already registered id: ~G_v1_Namespace|~X|rabbitmq-system'`. I tried using patches to get rid of this unwanted namespace however, it looks like that works only if ONE resource is defined. As soon as I add the other resource, it stops working.

```
bases:
  - ../../base
namespace: test

resources:
- https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/releases/download/v1.13.0/cluster-operator.yml
- https://github.com/rabbitmq/messaging-topology-operator/releases/download/v1.6.0/messaging-topology-operator.yaml

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - |-
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Namespace
    metadata:
      name: rabbitmq-system
    $patch: delete
```

What I think is happening is Kustomize loads the resources first and finds two identical Namespaces defined and it doesn't take patches into consideration. Can I fix this behavior somehow?

Comment: The `resources` field is for layering, what you are looking for seems to better fit `components`. https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/config_management/components/, maybe check that :)